# Ubuntu 13.10 and Dell Inspiron 7520 SE (Intel 4000 and ATI radeon HD 7730m)

Tags: dell, 13.10, brightness

I installed 13.10 and i have problems with my display. Everything else works fine. I cant control my brightness. I thought the graphics driver is the problem. So i went to software updates, switched to another driver (proprietary) and the Ubuntu screen went black and i wasn't able to boot either. I cant use my lap with such low brightness.

Then i reinstalled 13.10 again, This time full hdd reset. Same problem occurred. I grabbed radeon hd7730m for Linux x64 from the amd site, installed it, and the screen went black with only the "x" cursor showing on the next boot.

What should i need to do to make my brightness work and stabilize graphic cards as mine is switchable graphics type.

Comment: Have you solved this issue please ?

Comment: Please follow the instructions on this page (launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux) so Linux can support Hybrid-Graphics more efficiently

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my poor English.

If you can boot to login screen, then you don't have to reinstall your OS. You can only uninstall your AMD graphics proprietary driver to solve it.

In login screen, press "CTRL + ALT + F3" into command line, and login with your username.
Then use this command to uninstall your driver:

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
sudo reboot
```

If it works, then you can try Install the driver with this command

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates fglrx-pxpress
sudo reboot
```

But because of current compatibility issues, sometimes it is possible boot to "the screen went black with only the 'x' cursor showing". You can try it, or not for now and wait for some time before AMD improvement the driver.

Then about brightness problem. You can try

[Brightness issue in a Lenovo ThinkPad Edge LR236W5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363152/ubuntu-13-10-brightness-issue) or

http://lists.debian.org/debian-x/2012/06/msg00082.html

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 13.10 on Dell Inspiron 7520 SE (Intel and AMD Radeon H 7730m graphic cards)
I followed [this solution](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450&p=12832113#post12832113) and it enabled my ATI card, frankly I'm not sure if it will switch automatically !

Basically, after installing Ubuntu, run this command

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-pxpress
```

-**EDIT**-

If you face issues, check the discussion on this bug I opened recently. It has many great advices and links for dell inspiron machines.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1272781