# Unable to adjust screen brightness on acer extensa 5635z (ubuntu 13.10 )

Tags: grub2, 13.10, brightness, acer

I'm unable to adjust my screen brightness since I installed ubuntu 13.10, it was working correctly in 11.04.

I've already set

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

in `/etc/default/grub`, but no luck !!

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to follow the steps in another askubuntu question, that is :
[Brightness issue in a Lenovo ThinkPad Edge LR236W5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363152/ubuntu-13-10-brightness-issue)

or additionally in this page there are three steps you can follow:
https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/display

Comment: the second link, last solution !! : sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=50 , thanks