# Can't adjust the brightness on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, brightness, lenovo, thinkpad

I've got a new laptop ( Lenovo Thinkpad E145 ) and I can't adjust the brightness. When I press the brightness adjustment keyboards, I can see the window that appears top right corner which is showing that it is changing the brightness, but nothing happens. I can't adjust the brightness in settings either. 
I have tried some solutions suggesting editing the grub file, but they didn't work for me.

Thank you

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with my Lenovo Thinkpad E145. I have tried 13.10 and 14.04 nightly build from yesterday. On both versions it does not work however popup indicator shows that brightness is changing. On 14.04 when I change brightness slider in System Settings - Brightness & Lock it has effect only after Restart. Then again after reboot it's not possible to change brightness and slider in Settings preset automatically to maximum (and will take effect after next restart).

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem with my Acer Aspire One ZG5. Tried the suggestions on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363152/ubuntu-13-10-brightness-issue) site  but to no avail. Editing the grub works with Ubuntu 12.04 but not with 13.10. Help please?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after a fresh 13.10 installation. You have to enable the external graphics driver (with *Software & Updates → Additional drivers*). After the installation you have to reboot the system and it should work.